# Saving data to db on startup using spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to add some entity data into db on startup of spring boot application. I'm using spring data jpa repositories to save data to the db. I've tried using `@PostConstruct` annotation to a method and `ApplicationListener` interface, etc. but no success at all. Code is executed in both case but it doesn't write any data to db. How can I achieve it?

**Code :**

```
@Component
public class DatabaseFillerOnStartup implements ApplicationListener {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseFillerOnStartup.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        logger.info("===================================" +event.toString());
        User user = new User("test");
        user.setFirstName("test");
        user.setLastName("test");
        user.setEmail("test@test.com");
        user.setContactNumber("1234567890");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

**Configuration :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.furniturepool.bll.config" )
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties" )
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("domain.package" );
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

**Repository :**

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: I've found with Hibernate that the best thing to do is to set the log level as high as possible (although DEBUG will most likely do it) and to study the output thoroughly. There's quite often and error in the logs or at least a hint as to what to try next.

Comment: @JLove : let me check with debug mode

Comment: @JLove : I can read data from db... but saving not working .... it's just returning the object itself , without throwing any kind of error

Comment: Can you please post your repository code as well as your Hibernate configuration code.

Comment: @JLove : ok i will post after few minutes

Comment: I've added an example project below. Please note that Spring Boot provides a default Datasource, it may well be the cause of your issue as you are providing a second in your config. The example I've created uses JpaRepository which, for the example, will function in the same was as CrudRepository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any of the rest of your config, I've put together a sample application which uses a H2 database as storage, and a JpaRepository to store and retrieve a User.

[spring-data-jpa-repository-example](https://github.com/r-giskard-reventlov/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-repo-example)

Just run the test I've added.

Example config for Mysql DB:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    test-on-borrow: true
    validation-query: SELECT 1
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
```

Remember to add MySQL to your classpath.

Hope this helps.

Justin

Comment: Thanks for your help :) , but can I create the data to production machine using test code?

Comment: @PranavCBalan This is production ready code, I've just created it as a Junit test so that I don't need to setup the rest of the application. Please note my comment above regarding datasources also mark as the answer if it resolves you issue.

Comment: I need to write that data to the production server

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Ok, so in application.yaml swap the configuration of the H2 in-memory database for a disk based database. I think this is a separate issue from whether you can store and retrieve correctly from the repository.

Comment: I've ammended my answer to include the config which can be used for a MySQL db.

Comment: I need to use mysql db.... since in-memory data may destroy on next restart

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have commit the transaction yet?
or put your 'userrepository' code and spring-data-jpa xml configuration here.

Comment: The life-cycle of the entities are handled by the repository, without explicitly defining a transaction, the boundary for the transaction will be each method call on the repository. You shouldn't need to commit.